# SegFault in Reversing Line of 2D Array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to reverse the lines of a 2D array of doubles.
Since the array is dynamic, it's created like

```
double** revArr = new double*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    revArr[i] = new double[n];
```

I end up copying the original array to the reversed array by normal fashion

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        revArr[i][j] = arr[i][j];
```

Now here comes the kicker! Then I try to reverse the line of the array, and have tried a few different ways.

```
int start = 0, end = n;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    while (start < end)
    {
        double *temp = revArr[start];
        revArr[start] = revArr[end];
        revArr[end] = temp;
        start++; end--;
    }
}
```

Which since the array is an array of double*, it throws a SegFault that I'm not really sure how to fix!

I've tried using `std::swap`, I've tried using `std::reverse`, I'm not really sure where to turn to from here.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int m = 4, n = 4;

    double* arr = new double[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        arr[i] = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            arr[i][j] = i + j;

    int start = 0; end = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        while (start < end)
        {
            double *temp = arr[start];
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;
            start++; end--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and run ourselves.

Comment: You got it! Give me a second.

Comment: `revArr` is has size `m`, and you're trying to access `revArr[n]`. If n>m-1, you get Undefined Behavior. (And in any case, you probably won't get the behavior you intended.)

Comment: @Beta ```revArr``` has a size m by n

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the order of the (whole) lines, or to reverse the numbers in *each* line? Your code seems to be uncertain what it is being tasked with!

Comment: So say the first line ```1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0```, the reversed line is ```4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0```

Comment: Have you had a look at [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)? Are you set on using `new[]` / `delete[]`? Wouldn't `std::vector` do all this work for you?

Comment: I hate to ask, but why aren't you using `std::vector<T>`? You don't even deallocate the pointer you allocate with `new`. Moreover, your example doesn't run due to common syntactical errors.

Comment: I'm sure vector works a lot better, but this is for an assignment. How would it work with a vector?

Comment: To reverse a `std::vector` you feed the `std::vector::begin()` and `std::vector::end()` iterators into `std::reverse`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: But in your current code, `arr[start] = arr[end];`, `arr` has maximum index of `m - 1`, not `n` as `end` equals.

Comment: Outside of that issue, how would I fix the expected `double*` to `double` error thrown?

Comment: `double* arr = new double[m];` is supposed to be `double** arr = new double*[m];` just like in the code at the top of your question. Not sure why you didn't do this in your [example].

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo in my MRE, it is defined in my code as `double** revArr = new double*[m]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** From the OP's comment below, it appears he wanted to swap the numbers on each line instead of the lines themselves. The code should be changed to:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n / 2; j++) {
        std::swap(arr[i][j], arr[i][n - j - 1]);
    }
}
```

---

Here are a few suggestions from my side:

1. **Use the standard library**: The standard library exists for a reason and there is no reason *not to use it*. For example you can easily reverse the array like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    std::reverse_copy(arr[i], arr[i] + n, revArr[i]); // if you are copying the reversed array onto another
```

OR

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    std::reverse(arr[i], arr[i] + n);              // Copy the reversed result onto the same array
```

2. Always remember to `delete[]` your `new[]`-ed arrays after usage, or consider using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) or even [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). In this case:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    delete[] arr[i];
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: Thank you, for anyone wondering, from my original code you can use 
```for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { std::reverse(revArr[i], revArr[i] + n }```

Comment: The first part of your answer (on its own) *does not* address the multiple problems in the OP's code. However, changing `end = n` to `end = m - 1` *does* work when using the `std::reverse` function(s), as described in the second part of your answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole The answer to that lies in the first three snippets of his question itself.

Comment: Not really! OP wants to swap the **numbers** in each line, but their code is swapping **pointers**. Your use of `std::reverse` works, but then there is no need for the `start` and `end` variables at all. In the OP's code, `start` and `end` need to be reset on each run of the outer loop, and the body-code of the inner loop needs to be *drastically* changed.

Comment: In fact, I tested your hypothesis that, *"end = n should be end = m - 1 and the program will run just fine"* and, as expected, the code then reverses the *order* of the lines (but not their *content*); further, the for loop is then completely redundant, as `start < end` will be permanently FALSE after the first loop.

Comment: @AdrianMole You are right. Edited the answer to comply with his actual question.

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me :

```
int m = 4, n = 4;

double** arr = new double*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    arr[i] = new double[n];

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        arr[i][j] = static_cast<double>(i) + static_cast<double>(j);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < (n / 2); j++) {//note : i think, a "for" loop is more explicit
        double temp = arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][n - j - 1];
        arr[i][n - j - 1] = temp;
    }

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    delete[] arr[i];
delete[] arr;
```

But, as previously said, it's better to use the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the number in each (separate) line, then you shouldn't be looking at swapping the pointers. Each pointer will be to the start of each line, and you can access the n-th element of the m-th line as a simple `double` value, `arr[m][n]`.

Next, be aware the the last element of an array with `n` elements has an index of `n-1`, *not* `n`, so you should initialise `end` as `n-1`, or `arr[end]` will be out-of-bounds on the first run through your swapping loop (which is the cause of the `SegFault` exception).

Then, you need to reset `start` and `end` at the start of **each** line swap - i.e. **inside** the outer `for` loop.

So, considering the above, your reversal code should look (something) like this:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int start = 0; end = n - 1; // These need to be reset for EACH LINE.
        while (start < end)
        {
            double temp = arr[m][start];
            arr[m][start] = arr[m][end];
            arr[m][end] = temp;
            start++; end--;
        }
    }
```

Further, what you also need to do is to free the memory that you've allocated with your `new` operators, when you've finished with the data. So, at (or near) the end of your `main`, you should have code like this:

```c
//...
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        delete[] arr[i]; // Delete this 'line'
    delete[] arr; // And the delete the array of line pointers
    return 0; // Good practice to explicitly return 0 (success code) from main!
}
```

And, finally, you would be *far* better off using the `std::vector` container, rather than dynamically created arrays. Here's how you could do it with `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // For std::reverse
int main()
{
    size_t m = 4, n = 4;
    // Create/populate vectors:
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > arr(m);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i].push_back(double(i + j));
        }
    }
    // Reverse each line:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        std::reverse(arr[i].begin(), arr[i].end());
    }
    // Display results:
    for (auto a: arr) {
        for (auto d : a) {
            std::cout << d << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```